# I get an undefined error in php

Tags: php, html

I am trying to create 2 dropdown menus. One for displaying a list of buildings and then when user selects a building from the list, it will display the list of rooms in that building.

Problem is I have an error in my code. Below is the code:

```
      $sql="SELECT Building, Room FROM Room WHERE Building = '".$building."'";

      $sqlresult = mysql_query($sql);

      $sqldataArray = array();

      while($sqlrow = mysql_fetch_array($sqlresult))
   {
      $sqldataArray[$sqlrow['Building']]; 
      $sqldataArray[$sqlrow['Building']]['Rooms'][$sqlrow['Room']]; 
   }


       $buildingHTML = ""; 
       $buildingHTML .= '<select name="buildings" id="buildingssDrop">'.PHP_EOL;
       $buildingHTML .= '<option value="">Please Select</option>'.PHP_EOL; 

   foreach ($sqldataArray as $building => $buildingData) {      

            $buildingHTML .= "<option value='".$building."'>" . $building . "</option>".PHP_EOL;        

            }
            $buildingHTML .= '</select>';


       $roomHTML = ""; 
       $roomHTML .= '<select name="rooms" id="roomsDrop">'.PHP_EOL;
       $roomHTML .= '<option value="">Please Select</option>'.PHP_EOL;      
            foreach ($buildingData['Rooms'] as $roomId => $roomData) {        

            $roomHTML .= "<option value='".$roomId."'>" . $roomId . "</option>".PHP_EOL;        
  } 

            $roomHTML .= '</select>';
```

The error I am getting is this:

Undefined variable: buildingData in /web/stud/u0867587/Mobile_app/create_session.php on line 372

This is the line of code where the error is:

```
$buildingHTML .= "<option value='".$building"'>" . $building . "</option>".PHP_EOL;
```

Does anyone know how to fix this error. I believe it is because it is not in the other foreach loop but if I put that in, then does it affect the display of the dropdown menu?

Comment: Are you sure that's the right line? I don't see any `$buildingData` in that line.

Comment: Are you positive about a 'Rooms' element in the array? print_r($buildingData) to check its content.

Comment: The error is on the next foreach line where he's trying to access `$buildingData` outside of the scope of the previous `foreach` where it's declared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not entirely sure what you're trying to get as a final output - there's a few logical issues with your code

Take a look at this minor rewrite - this will produce a <select> for buildings, and a <select> for all the rooms in your first building.

```
<?php

$sqlresult = mysql_query($sql);

$buildings = array(); // easier if you don't use generic names for data

while($sqlrow = mysql_fetch_array($sqlresult))
{
    // you need to initialise your building array cells
    if (!isset($buildings[$sqlrow['Building']])) {
        $buildings[$sqlrow['Building']] = array('Rooms' => array());
    }

    // you can add the room to the building 'Rooms' array
    $buildings[$sqlrow['Building']]['Rooms'][] = $sqlrow['Room']]);
}


$buildingHTML = ""; 
$buildingHTML .= '<select name="buildings" id="buildingssDrop">'.PHP_EOL;
$buildingHTML .= '<option value="">Please Select</option>'.PHP_EOL; 

foreach ($buildings as $building => $buildingData) {      
    $buildingHTML .= "<option value='".$building."'>" . $building . "</option>".PHP_EOL;        
}
$buildingHTML .= '</select>';

$roomHTML = ""; 
$roomHTML .= '<select name="rooms" id="roomsDrop">'.PHP_EOL;
$roomHTML .= '<option value="">Please Select</option>'.PHP_EOL;      
foreach ($buildings['Building Number 1']['Rooms'] as $roomId => $roomData) {        
    $roomHTML .= "<option value='".$roomId."'>" . $roomId . "</option>".PHP_EOL;        
} 

$roomHTML .= '</select>';
```

Comment: Hi, I am getting this error: 
Notice: Undefined index: Rooms in /web/stud/u0867587/Mobile_app/create_session.php on line 374 which is for this code: `foreach ($buildings[0]['Rooms'] as $roomId => $roomData) `. What my final output is that for the 'buildings" dropdown menu, it should display the buildings from the database table which is 'Canalside West' and 'Canalside East' and then for the rooms textbox, it will be empty until user has selected a building, when user selects a building then it should show a list of rooms which belongs to the building select in the first dropdown menu.

Comment: I'm guessing that the problem is that you don't have $buildings[0] is not set - since you are created a building array keyed by the name of the building, so try $buildings['Canalside West']. To get the list of rooms to change depending on the building option requires quite a bit more - and probably should be asked in a different question.

Answer (score 1):

You have a few issues.

1. These lines don't do anything:

   - `$sqlrow['Building']];`
   - `$sqldataArray[$sqlrow['Building']]['Rooms'][$sqlrow['Room']];`
2. You're trying to reference `$buildingData` *after* your `foreach` which defines it has closed.  When your next `foreach` loop tries to use it, it's `null`, because you're outside the scope of the preceding `foreach`. **This is causing your error message.**

You should consider taking a higher-level look at your application logic and decide how it should be laid out with pseudocode first.

(edit: SO doesn't let you put code blocks inside lists? why?!)

Comment: Could this work for defining variables:    `$sqldataArray[$sqlrow['Building']] = $sqlrow['Building'] ; 
   $sqldataArray[$sqlrow['Building']]['Rooms'][$sqlrow['Room']] = $sqlrow['Room'];`

Comment: Do you know how I should lay it out so foreach loops are in correct places without messing up drop down menus?

Answer (score 0):

You're not defining any variables:

```
  $sqldataArray[$sqlrow['Building']]; 
  $sqldataArray[$sqlrow['Building']]['Rooms'][$sqlrow['Room']];
```

Should be something like:

```
  $sqldataArray[$sqlrow['Building']] = "Value"; 
  $sqldataArray[$sqlrow['Building']]['Rooms'][$sqlrow['Room']] = "Definition";
```

Comment: Ummm you cannot do `$sqldataArray[$sqlrow['Building']]['Rooms'][$sqlrow['Room']]` because `$sqldataArray[$sqlrow['Building']]` is a **string**

Comment: Could this work for defining variables:    `$sqldataArray[$sqlrow['Building']] = $sqlrow['Building'] ; 
   $sqldataArray[$sqlrow['Building']]['Rooms'][$sqlrow['Room']] = $sqlrow['Room'];`

Comment: Do you know how I should lay it out so foreach loops are in correct places without messing up drop down menus?